# Gradle and library issues while importing a project into Android Studio.

Tags: android

I am importing an old project into android studio, getting gradle and library issues.

[Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uo4uem6hwhecemi/android.zip?dl=0) imported.

After solving gradle issue am getting below error message

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
```

> [declare-styleable/CircularImageView] /home/appristine/Aks_Projct/Bazaaralosra/res/values/attrs.xml   [declare-styleable/CircularImageView] /home/appristine/Aks_Projct/Bazaaralosra/res/values/styles.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

Comment: open that file and remove duplicates

Comment: when i remove that files its give Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

Comment: what is compileSDK version

Comment: Post your layout xml file & styles xml files. Its easy to solve problem. Remove those Text appearance style in buttons. Because that android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Co‌​lored is not in your android studio or styles. Therefore No resource found for that style. Find where its uses in layouts and delete them.

Comment: compile SDK version is 21

Comment: <declare-styleable name="CircularImageView">
        <attr name="border" format="boolean"></attr>
        <attr name="border_width" format="dimension"></attr>
        <attr name="border_color" format="color"></attr>
        <attr name="shadow" format="boolean"></attr>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="Theme">
        <attr name="circularImageViewStyle" format="reference"></attr>
    </declare-styleable>

Comment: I think this  is a old project